# JavaScript Date Month Out

Tags: javascript, date

I am creating a jQuery UI slider and need to create a date range from 19th Jan '15 to today 6th May '17.

I have calculated there to be 777 days between these dates.

However when I do this in JavaScript it is 30 days out.

```js
var startDate = new Date(2015, 1, 19);
var endDate = new Date();
var timeDiff = Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

$("#result").html(diffDays);

$("#diff").html(777 - diffDays);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
JS: <span id="result"></span><br>
Actual: 777<br>
Difference: <span id="diff"></span>
```

I don't see any errors with my code as I have used it elsewhere and it functions correctly.

Comment: Months are numbered from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months in JavaScript are zero-based, so January is `0`, not `1`

```js
var startDate = new Date(2015, 0, 19);
var endDate = new Date();
var timeDiff = Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

$("#result").html(diffDays);

$("#diff").html(777 - diffDays);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
JS: <span id="result"></span><br>
Actual: 777<br>
Difference: <span id="diff"></span>
```

Note also that I changed ceil to floor

Comment: Why did you change ceil to floor?

Comment: Because ceil gave me 778 as the unrounded value for me was `777.4706272569445` since endDate includes the time.